# How to open .java in selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

try: 
i find some error

> "error loading test case: no command found"**strong text**

please help how to use selenium and why i cant open my .java in selenium iDE

Comment: which version of firefox browser you r using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Save File in IDE:
Stop recording --> Export test case as --> Java/Junit --> Give appropriate name and Save.

To open above file just click on File --> Open --> choose right file at right location.

Comment: keep eroor. iam just open  my .html file record to selenium ide

Comment: May be the file which you opened is not saved properly. You will get such type of error if no commands are exist in opened file.

Comment: i get error if i open my export .java record to selenium IDE